# What does 'string is not terminated' mean?

Tags: string

Excuse my ignorance, but I don't know what the phrase means. I have a few questions:

1. is there any difference between
   'string is not terminated' and
   'string is not null terminated'?
2. What is it?
3. How does a non terminated string look like?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Where/who/what says a string is "not terminated"? Is this an error message?

Comment: In what language are you getting the error?

Comment: what language? where in the process are you seeing the problem? maybe give us a sanitized code snippet?

Comment: Unless you also provide a length, there's no way to tell when a non terminated string ends*7jd@jh#MV*()>SDk+!^ &@P&]JEA&#65535;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the context.  When someone talks about a string being null-terminated, they usually are talking about a C-style string, which is simply an array of characters, followed by a 0-byte at the end, sometimes refered to as \0 or null.

This stands in contrast to string datatypes which instead store their length at the beginning, and then an array of characters.  In this case, the string "yo!" would be represented as:

```
Length  Char0 Char1 Char2
------  ----- ----- -----
  3       y     o     !
```

When someone talks about a string "not being terminated", they're usually talking about a string that is not enclosed by two sets of quotes -- this is the kind of error a compiler will give you.  It's a totally different thing.

Answer (score 1):

"string not terminated" usually means you are missing the closing quote for your string.